# The generated tests(producer side) failed in Spring Cloud contract and AMQP/RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-contract

I was trying to use AMQP/RabbitMQ and Spring cloud contract in my microservice projects to define the contract between producers and consumers.

I am using the last Spring Boot 2.0.3, and Spring Cloud Contract 2.0.0.

I have prepared a sample project to reproduce the problem.

- [producer](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-cloud-sample/tree/master/contract-producer-amqp)
- [consumer](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-cloud-sample/tree/master/contract-consumer-amqp)

In the **producer side**, I created a base test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "stubrunner.amqp.enabled=true")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
public class MessageVerifierBase {

    @Autowired
    MessageVerifier verifier;

    @Autowired
    Sender sender;

    public void send() {
        this.sender.send(Notification.builder().body("test message").build());
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        verifier.receive("notification.exchange", 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

The `Sender` just called `RabbitTemplate`.

```
    @Component
public class Sender {

    @Autowired
    AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    public void send(Notification notification){
        this.amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("notification.exchange", "notification.messages", notification);
    }

}
```

And created the contract in groovy format.

```
    org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
    description("""
        send messages by rabbitmq
    """)
    label "notification.event"
    // input to the contract
    input {
        // the contract will be triggered by a method
        triggeredBy('send()')
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo "notification.exchange"
        body([
            body: "test message",
            type: "MESSAGE"
        ])
        headers {
            header("contentType", applicationJsonUtf8())
            header("__TypeId__", "com.example.demo.Notification")
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran `mvn clean install`, it failed, and reported the following problem:

```
    Wanted but not invoked:
rabbitTemplate.send(
    "notification.exchange",
    <Capturing argument>,
    <Capturing argument>,
    <any org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.CorrelationData>
);
-> at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.amqp.SpringAmqpStubMessages.receive(SpringAmqpStubMessages.java:110)

However, there were exactly 3 interactions with this mock:
rabbitTemplate.getMessageConverter();
-> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitMessagingTemplate.afterPropertiesSet(RabbitMessagingTemplate.java:111)

rabbitTemplate.getMessageConverter();
-> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitMessagingTemplate.afterPropertiesSet(RabbitMessagingTemplate.java:113)

rabbitTemplate.getMessageConverter();
-> at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.amqp.ContractVerifierAmqpAutoConfiguration.contractVerifierMessaging(ContractVerifierAmqpAutoConfiguration.java:82)
```

Comment: You need to show your test case.

Comment: And tell us which version of contract you are using

Comment: @GaryRussell I have already added base test, it will generate `MessagingTest` will run `mvn clean install`.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak updated, and added version info.  I have used Spring Cloud Contract in before experience, but not used **messaging**.

Comment: could you please upload a sampler to github?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak updated the content, share my codes  on github, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-cloud-sample

Comment: Added another [Integration/AMQP samples](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-cloud-sample), and got the same errors. But in the **stream**, **rest** samples, the tests of producer side work.

Comment: Classpath problem?

Comment: @theMayer in Spring Cloud Contract 1.1. the work-offline will make it search local maven repos, but 2.0 stubsMode(instead of work-offline?) provides LOCAL, REMOTE, CLASSPATH options.

Comment: @theMayer I moved the consumer failure into another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120041/sprign-cloud-contract-consumer-side-can-not-find-stubs-from-local-maven-repos maybe more clear.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak [all of my consumer side](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-cloud-sample) can not find stubs from local maven repos in this new version 2.0.0, in 1.x the work-offline worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120041/sprign-cloud-contract-consumer-side-can-not-find-stubs-from-local-maven-repos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fixed the issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/676 . The problem was with Mockito migration (and 2 missing tests that I've added). So the Mockito verification whether a passed object is of a given class changed its behaviour. In previous versions it accepted nulls, now it doesn't. There were missing tests to verify the null, otherwise, obviously we would have caught it earlier. Thanks for the report, thanks for the sample.